# How to find expected value for it?

Tags: calculus, probability

A stock market trader buys 100 shares of stock A and 200 shares of stock B. Let X and Y be the price changes of stock A and B, respectively, over a certain time period, and assume that the Joint PDF of X and Y is uniform over the set
of integers x and y satisfying −2 ≤ x ≤ 4 −1 ≤ y − x ≤ 1. Find the mean of the traders profit.

My solution is following:

[image: Bang]

As the area of the shaded region is 12, the Joint PDF will be 1/12. So I think the answer will be this integral:

[image: this integral].

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: Hello. I have added my solution for this problem. I want to check whether it is correct or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the area of the shaded region is 12, the Joint PDF will be 1/12. So I think the answer will be this integral:
>
> [image: this integral].

Close. Check the order of integrations.

$$\mathsf E(100X+200Y)~=~\int_{-2}^4\int_{x-1}^{x+1}\tfrac 1{12}(100x+200y)\,\mathrm d\, y\;\mathrm d\, x$$

> Also as obviously $\mathsf E(X)=1$, and $\mathsf E(Y)=\mathsf E(\mathsf E(Y\mid X))=1$, then $\mathsf E(100X+200Y)= 300$.